# Error reading xml file from resources in Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, fileinputstream

Error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [xml/ruleSet.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app/target/******-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/xml/ruleSet.xml
```

Code :

```
File ruleSet = new ClassPathResource("xml/ruleSet.xml").getFile();
pmdConfiguration.setReportFormat("text");
pmdConfiguration.setRuleSets(ruleSet.getAbsolutePath());
```

I need to insert the full file into the setRuleSets method, how will FileInputStream help me here?

```
FileInputStream ruleSet = new FileInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemResource
                    ("xml/ruleSet.xml").getPath());
```

Should I recreate a temp file by reading the fileinput stream and pass that file path to `setRuleSets` method?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that there is no path *in the file system namespace* for a resource in a JAR file.  That is why `ClassPathResource::getFile` is throwing an exception, and it is also why `URL::getPath`.

There is an alternative.  Use an `InputStream`, not a `FileInputStream`, and use the classloader API method for opening a resource as a stream.

Change:

```
    FileInputStream ruleSet = new FileInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemResource
                    ("xml/ruleSet.xml").getPath());
```

to

```
    InputStream ruleSet = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("xml/ruleSet.xml");
```

In this case, this won't work because `PMDConfiguration::setRuleSets` doesn't take a stream argument.

However, the [javadoc](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/apidocs/net/sourceforge/pmd/PMDConfiguration.html#setRuleSets(java.lang.String)) states:

> ```
> public void setRuleSets(String ruleSets)
> ```
>
> Set the command<sup>1</sup> separated list of RuleSet URIs.

Since the `getResource` methods return a URL, you *should* be able to do this:

```
    pmdConfiguration.setRuleSets(
        ClassLoader.getSystemResource("xml/ruleSet.xml").toString();
```

**UPDATE**

If `getSystemResource` or `getSystemResourceAsStream` fails, then either the resource does not exist (in the JARs, etc on the runtime classpath), the path is incorrect, or you should be using `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`.

---

<sup>1 - The word "command" is a typo.  It should be "comma".</sup>

Comment: adding toString to "ClassLoader.getSystemResource("xml/ruleSet.xml").toString()" fails, I also tried `pmdConfiguration.setRuleSets(
                        ClassLoader.getSystemResource("xml/ruleSet.xml").getPath());` it passes in local but fails in heroku.

System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("xml/ruleSet.xml"));
                System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("xml/ruleSet.xml"));

Both returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I figured out what to do here,

We already have input stream, thus I converted input stream to a temp file, and used that file.getPath.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("xml/ruleSet.xml");
String ruleSetFilePath = "";
if(resourceAsStream != null){
    File file = stream2file(resourceAsStream);
    ruleSetFilePath = file.getPath();

}
pmdConfiguration.setRuleSets(ruleSetFilePath);

public static File stream2file (InputStream in) throws IOException {
final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("ruleSet", ".xml");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
}
return tempFile;
}
```